# Creating a Black Hole Folder ('Hawking Dimensional') Variant in Linux (Slackware)?

Tags: linux, permissions, shared-folders

I would like to create a folder that any user can add a file/folder to (if it is not a duplicate) but only root can access... Or could be read by the user but only changed by root.. It is a simple idea in concept anyway...

Comment: In what way? Local access, or network access? What type of network access?

Comment: I was referring to a local share. The 300 setting is what I had for the first part. I had changed the user and forgot to set the mask. But in reality the second part would be more useful (again local). I tend to load files to my computer while working on multiple things and forget which folder they are in.... A simple as possible multilayered deletion resistant system would be advantageous ....